# How to use DHTMLX library with codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, gantt-chart, dhtmlx

I am trying to include a gantt chart in my codeigniter application. Tutorial I followed step by step is: https://docs.dhtmlx.com/tutorials__connector_codeigniter__step6.html

After following all steps when I hit the route...
I got the error:
[image]

When I looked deep into issue, and hit the controller directly I got the issue that is:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Class 'Dhtmlx\Connector\GanttConnector' not found

Filename: D:\Xampp\htdocs\main_project_folder\sub_folder\application\controllers\Gantt.php

Line Number: 10

Backtrace:

File: D:\Xampp\htdocs\main_project_folder\sub_folder\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Sub_folder is actual project folder and inside it I have copy paste dhtmlx, dhtmlxGantt and dhtmlxScheduler folder.
I don't know that why it is not finding it.
Anyone who has experience working with Gantt in codeigniter? Any help would be highly appreciated. You can also suggest me some other way of including Gantt in codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

It's look like you don't have file in directory.

You can download connector here: 
https://github.com/DHTMLX/connector-php/tree/master/codebase 
and put it to folder with another connectors.